# What is an effective way to bulk create objects with related objects in django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-queryset

I have the following models:

```
class LocationPoint(models.Model):
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=12)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=16, decimal_places=12)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (
            ('latitude', 'longitude',),
        )
```

```
class GeoLogEntry(models.Model):
    device = models.ForeignKey(Device, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    location_point = models.ForeignKey(LocationPoint, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    recorded_at = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
```

I have lots of incoming records to create (probably thousands at once).

Currently I create them like this:

```
# Simplified map function contents (removed mapping from dict as it's unrelated to the question topic
points_models = map(lambda point: LocationPoint(latitude=latitude, longitude=longitude), points)

LocationPoint.objects.bulk_create(
     points_models,
     ignore_conflicts=True
)

# Simplified map function contents (removed mapping from dict as it's unrelated to the question topic
geo_log_entries = map(
            lambda log_entry: GeoLogEntry(device=device, location_point=LocationPoint.objects.get(latitude=latitude, longitude=longitude), recorded_at=log_entry.recorded_at),
            log_entries
        )

GeoLogEntry.objects.bulk_create(geo_log_entries, ignore_conflicts=True)
```

But I think it's not very effective because it runs `N` `SELECT` queries for `N` records. Is there a better way to do that?

I use Python 3.9, Django 3.1.2 and PostgreSQL 12.4.

Comment: I assume it is `lambda point: LocationPoint(latitude=point.latitude, ...))`, so `point.latitde` instead of `latitutude`?

Comment: I can also recommend one dirty solution. Execute that part asynchronously using something like `celery` if you don't actually need to return created objects as response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is to fetch the objects to link to in bulk to. We can fetch the objects in bulk once we stored all of these objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

points_models = [
    LocationPoint(latitude=point.latitude, longitude=point.longitude)
    for point in points
]

LocationPoint.objects.bulk_create(
     points_models,
     ignore_conflicts=True
)

qfilter = Q(
    *[
          Q(('latitude', point.latitude), ('longitude', point.longitude))
          for point in log_entries
    ],
    _connector=Q.OR
)


data = {
    (lp.longitude, lp.latitude): lp.pk
    for lp in LocationPoint.objects.filter(qfilter)
}

geo_log_entries = [
    GeoLogEntry(
        device=entry.device,
        location_point_id=data[entry.longitude, entry.latitude],
        recorded_at=entry.recorded_at
    )
    for entry in log_entries
]

GeoLogEntry.objects.bulk_create(geo_log_entries, ignore_conflicts=True)
```

We thus fetch all the objects in bulk that we need to link to (with one query thus), make a dictionary that maps the longitude and latitude on the primary key, and then set `location_point_id` to that point.

It is however important that one uses decimals, or at least a type that will match. Floating points are *tricky*, since these can easily have rounding errors (therefore often longitudes and latitudes are stored as "*fixed point*" numbers, so for example integers that are a factor 1'000 larger or 1'000'000 larger). Otherwise you should use an algorithm that matches it with the data that is generated through querying.

Comment: Thanks! That's much faster for queries (86 ms vs 1100 ms) on 1000 records, but still slow on Python side (4.4 s vs 16 s). Any tips on how to optimize it?

Comment: @artem: for a dictionary this should not be that slow. For linear search that is of course a different story. You can perhaps try to profile where exactly the performance gap is located.

Comment: Seems that it's just debug template rendering time (+ debug toolbar costs), and creating `data` time cost grows fast with grow of record count (10k takes 20 seconds to create `data` on python side), but I think I'll optimize it. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

`bulk_create(...)` will return you created objects as a list. You can filter those objects on Python side, instead of making queries to your DB, as they are already fetched.

```
location_points = LocationPoint.objects.bulk_create(
     points_models,
     ignore_conflicts=True
)

geo_log_entries = map(
    lambda log_entry: GeoLogEntry(
        device=device, 
        location_point=get_location_point(log_entry, location_points),      
        recorded_at=log_entry.recorded_at
    ),
    log_entries
)

GeoLogEntry.objects.bulk_create(geo_log_entries, ignore_conflicts=True)
```

All you need to do is implement `get_location_point` satisfying your needs

Comment: The problem is that it will for most databases not fill in the primary key in the objects, so that means that one can not use these to assign a value to `location_point`.

Comment: Yep, PK is null for the created objects.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem AFAIK using Postgres 12 along with Django 3 is sufficient for primary keys to be set. OP specified that he is using Django 3.1.2 and PostgreSQL 12.4

Comment: @artem hmm, OK then. I just Though that I did that once...

Comment: [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create) says that primary keys must be set though

Comment: @vagifm just checked, list is returned, but PKs are null: https://pastebin.com/CD8nyTky

Comment: @artem can you also check for `.id` field, not just `.pk`. Just to make sure

Comment: @vagifm ok, seems that it's because I use the `ignore_conflicts` flag. But I think I must use it to guarantee thread safety